# Reset background in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UIPageViewController` displaying a `UIImageView`.

I can swipe and everything is displayed correctly: [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yky5k.jpg)

There is an "Edit" button that pushes another `ViewController` on the screen:

```
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(editPictureViewController, animated: true)
```

When `editPictureViewController` is closed:

- either by clicking the Back button
- or by calling the Done button  `navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true))`

the background of the `UIPageViewController` is not white anymore: it's "Image 1" (the image that was displayed before `editPictureViewController` was pushed).
If I swipe to see the previous image, the background is not white. See here: [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMHPh.jpg)

What's the problem with the background?

Comment: After back to `UIPageViewcontroller`, you want to show edited image or plain(clear) background(which is `UIImageView`) without image right..?

Comment: When the back button is pressed, the correct image is displayed (Image 1). The problem is that if I swipe to get the previous view controller, the background is not white anymore, it's Image 1. The screen looks like Image 2: the image is displayed correctly but the background is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found the issue... I was initiating the UIPageViewController in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad :-/